# Flutter - Allow multiple selection from autocomplete and display as chips, with free text input

Tags: flutter

I am building an app in Flutter where I need to allow the user to select multiple values from an autocomplete dropdown, display the selections as chips, and also allow free text input if the desired value is not in the list.

I have the autocomplete working with the following code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AutoCompeleteCustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String apiUrl;
  final String placeholder;
  final Function(List<String>) onSelectionChanged; // Callback function

  AutoCompeleteCustomWidget({
    required this.apiUrl,
    required this.placeholder,
    required this.onSelectionChanged, // Include the callback in the constructor
  });

  @override
  State<AutoCompeleteCustomWidget> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<AutoCompeleteCustomWidget> {
  late String apiUrl;
  late String placeholder;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    apiUrl = widget.apiUrl;
    placeholder = widget.placeholder;
  }

  final myController = TextEditingController();
  List<String> names = [];
  List<String> selected = [];

  void searchNames(String query) async {
    final url = Uri.parse('$apiUrl?limit=10&q=$query');
    var response = await http.get(url);
    setState(() {
      var users = jsonDecode(response.body)['users'];
      names = List<String>.from(users.map((user) => user['firstName']));
    });
  }

  var titleTextStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   title: Text('Autocomplete Demo', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
      // ),

      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          // Display selected items above the search input
          selected.isNotEmpty
              ? Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                    child: Wrap(
                      spacing: 8.0,
                      children: selected
                          .map(
                            (name) => InputChip(
                              label: Text(name),
                              onDeleted: () {
                                setState(() => selected.remove(name));
                                // Call the callback with the updated selected list
                                widget.onSelectionChanged(selected);
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(), // Empty container if no selected items
          SizedBox(height: 16.0), // Add vertical space here
          TextField(
            controller: myController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: placeholder,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
            ),
            onChanged: (value) => searchNames(value),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: names.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final name = names[index];

                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(name, style: titleTextStyle),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selected.add(name);
                      myController.text = '';
                      names.clear();
                    });
                    // Call the callback with the updated selected list
                    widget.onSelectionChanged(selected);
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This works well for a single selection. However, when I try to use this component multiple times on a page, I run into layout issues with the autocomplete suggestions overlaying each other.

I tried wrapping the widget in a SizedBox to constrain the height, but then the suggestions no longer display properly:

```dart
ListView(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  child: AutoCompeleteCustomWidget(
                      apiUrl: 'https://dummyjson.com/users/search',
                      placeholder: 'Symptoms',
                      onSelectionChanged: (selected) {
                        symptoms = selected;
                      })),
              SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  child: AutoCompeleteCustomWidget(
                      apiUrl: 'https://dummyjson.com/users/search',
                      placeholder: 'Analysis',
                      onSelectionChanged: (selected) {
                        analysis = selected;
                      })),
```

My main questions are:

1. How can I allow for multiple selection from the autocomplete and display these as chips?
2. How can I prevent the autocomplete suggestions from overlapping when using multiple instances of this component?
3. Is there a way to also allow free text input in addition to selections?

I'm new to Flutter so any help is appreciated! Is there a better way to achieve this type of multi-select autocomplete with chips? Or how can I fix the issues with my current approach?

Application Versions
Flutter 3.16.3
Tools • Dart 3.2.3 • DevTools 2.28.4